# Show attribute in search result template only if contains highlighted matches

Tags: search, search-engine, algolia

I have several attributes set as `attributesToRetrieve`. In my template though only some of these are displayed. Roughly something like this:

```html
<div id="results">
  <div>{{_highlightResult.attr1.value}}</div>
  <div>{{_highlightResult.attr2.value}}</div>
  <div>{{_highlightResult.attr3.value}}</div>
</div>
```

This way the attributes will be rendered in any case, and highlighted if they contain a matched word.

Now I'd like to add another section where all other attributes can be displayed but **only if** they contain a matched word to be highlighted, something like:

```html
<div id="results">
  <div>{{_highlightResult.attr_1.value}}</div>
  <div>{{_highlightResult.attr_2.value}}</div>
  <div>{{_highlightResult.attr_3.value}}</div>
<!-- 
The following div will be rendered and displayed only 
if any of these special attributes contain an highlighted word. 
Only an attribute containing a matched word will be displayed 
-->
  <div class="other-attr">
    {{_highlightResult.Long_SpecialAttr_1.value}}
    {{_highlightResult.SpecialAttr_2.value}}
    {{_highlightResult.SpecialAttr_3.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

As mentioned in the comment, this section will be rendered and displayed only if any of these special attributes contain an highlighted word, also only an attribute containing a matched word will be displayed.

Plus as you can see there is a `Long_SpecialAttr_1`, it's a long text attribute, wich I'd like to have it displayed as a snippeted attribute.

To give a better idea (maybe) what I'm trying to achieve for this additional section is something like the one Google display below every search results, a sort of *text blob* text with ellipsis containing the marked words of these attributes.

Is this possible? I'm using algolia [instasearch.js](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/), thank you!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [@Jerska](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36958614/1262357) for his answer, unfortunately a small bit of code wasn't working in my case, specifically:

```js
['highlight', 'snippet'].forEach(function (type) {
  data['_' + type + 'Result'].forEach(function (elt) {
    elt.display = elt.matchLevel !== 'none';
  });
});
```

giving me an error in the console stating `data._snippetResult.forEach() is undefined`. So I modified that bit with this:

```js
for(var el in d._snippetResult)
{
  // create new property with bool value, true if not "none"
  d._snippetResult[el].display = d._snippetResult[el].matchLevel !== 'none';
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, just to clarify the settings of your index before going forward, Algolia also highlights the attributes in [`attributesToSnippet`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-attributesToSnippet).
Also, to have an ellipsis on the attributes you snippet, you can set [`snippetEllipsisText`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-snippetEllipsisText).
So you might want to use these settings in your index:

```coffee
attributesToHighlight: ['attr_1', 'attr_2', 'attr_3', 'SpecialAttr_2', 'SpecialAttr_3'],
attributesToSnippet: ['Long_SpecialAttr_1:3'], // Snippet should contain max 3 words
snippetEllipsisText: '…' // This is the utf-8 "Horizontal ellipsis" character
```

---

On the front-end side, in `instantsearch.js` you can use the `transformData` parameter on almost any widget to be able to access and/or modify the data passed to the template.

In this specific example, we'll want to have a look at [`transformData.item` on the `hits` widget](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#hits).

The first step would be to log the data:

```javascript
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    transformData: {
      item: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      }
    }
  })
);
```

This will allow you to see that kind of response:

```coffee
_highlightResult: {
  attr_1: {
    value: 'lorem <em>ipsum</em> dolor <em>sit</em>',
    matchLevel: 'full',
    matchedWords: ['ipsum', 'sit']
  },
  attr_2: {
    value: 'lorem <em>ipsum</em> dolor',
    matchLevel: 'partial',
    matchedWords: ['ipsum']
  },
  attr_3: {
    value: 'lorem',
    matchLevel: 'none',
    matchedWords: []
  },
  // ...
},
_snippetResult: {
  Long_SpecialAttr_1: {
    value: 'lorem <em>ipsum</em> dolor …', // Let's assume Long_SpecialAttr_1 was equal to 'lorem ipsum dolor sit'
    matchLevel: 'full'
  }
}
```

Unfortunately here, the API is a bit inconsistent since as you can see, snippeted attributes don't have the `matchedWords` attribute that highlighted attributes have. You can choose to set it both in `attributesToSnippet` and `attributesToHighlight` if you really want the info.

However, for your use-case, we just need `matchLevel`. What we want, is to display elements only if `matchLevel !== 'none'`. Unfortunately, [`Hogan.js`](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/), the underlying template engine of `instantsearch.js` doesn't allow for much flexibility, so you can't just put this comparison in your template.

A solution could be to precompute these conditions inside the `transformData`:

```javascript
transformData: {
  item: function (data) {
    ['highlight', 'snippet'].forEach(function (type) {
      var group = data['_' + type + 'Result'];
      for (var attr in group) {
        if (!group.hasOwnProperty(attr)) continue;
        var elt = group[attr];
        elt.display = elt.matchLevel !== 'none';
      };
    });
    data.displaySpecial = false ||
      data._snippetResult.Long_SpecialAttr_1.display ||
      data._highlightResult.SpecialAttr_2.display ||
      data._highlightResult.SpecialAttr_3.display;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And then use these new attributes in your template:

```html
<div id="results">
  <div>{{{_highlightResult.attr_1.value}}}</div>
  <div>{{{_highlightResult.attr_2.value}}}</div>
  <div>{{{_highlightResult.attr_3.value}}}</div>
<!-- 
The following div will be rendered and displayed only 
if any of these special attributes contain an highlighted word. 
Only an attribute containing a matched word will be displayed 
-->
  {{#displaySpecial}}
    <div class="other-attr">
      {{#_snippetResult.Long_SpecialAttr_1.display}}
        {{{_highlightResult.Long_SpecialAttr_1.value}}}
      {{/_snippetResult.Long_SpecialAttr_1.display}}

      {{#_highlightResult.SpecialAttr_2.display}}
        {{{_highlightResult.SpecialAttr_2.value}}}
      {{/_highlightResult.SpecialAttr_2.display}}

      {{#_highlightResult.SpecialAttr_3.display}}
        {{{_highlightResult.SpecialAttr_3.value}}}
      {{/_highlightResult.SpecialAttr_3.display}}
  </div>
  {{#displaySpecial}}
</div>
```

(By the way, to render HTML, you should use `{{{ ... }}}` instead of `{{...}}`, I've replaced them here)

Comment: Brilliant! thank a lot for this very detailed answer! :) I had a small problem with the `forEach`, the console error reported that there was a undefined function (I guess because you can cast `forEach` only on arrays, or did I overlooked something?), so I modified that bit like mentioned in the update.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed, I took my dreams for reality. ES5's `forEach` indeed doesn't work on objects whereas underscore/lodash 's `forEach` function does. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I see, but I think the one really lacking here could be me not using Lodash, yet :P